# ibus -> preferences doesn't show

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, locale, ibus, japanese

im trying to set my kubuntu to accept Japanese input, I followed this guide https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BkwgyevmSGk#t=95

I clicked ibus, But it does nothing, I cant see anything ibus on my system tray. Later I did this and it fixed the issue, ibus now showing on my tray properly

```
sudo im-config
```

and change the input method from default to iBus.
Then log out and login.

but whenever I right click the tray -> preferences -> it does nothing, nothing pop up on my side, it just does nothing. The other menu, (About, Restart, Quit) is working, but whenever I try to click "Preferences" it does nothing. Anyone can tell me what I missed?
Thanks

I'm on : Kubuntu 13.10

Comment: You should not use sudo when running the im-config command.

Comment: what should I do to fix it?

Comment: I'm not a Kubuntu user, but you should be able to access the IBus preferences dialog by running the ibus-setup command in a terminal window.

Comment: hey I have this error, is there something wrong with my ibus installation?

RROR:root:Could not find any typelib for Gtk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/ibus/setup/main.py", line 29, in <module>
    from gi.repository import Gtk
ImportError: cannot import name Gtk

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you run into https://launchpad.net/bugs/1258867, so

```
sudo apt-get install gir1.2-gtk-3.0
```

should do it.