# Ibus input method preferences window not showing in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, ibus, input-method

Edit Aug. 2022: Ubuntu has been through a lot in the past decade. The latest LTS, 22.04, has a slightly more friendly way for non-western languages.

Check out this more recent post: https://askubuntu.com/a/1408874/316146

- Use the Ubuntu Settings interface.
- Don't bother with fiddling with built-in Ibus or installing fcitx.
- Reboot after adding the language and before adding the input source.
- If you are not satisfied, save your efforts. Buy a Windows.

---

After installing IBUS and pinyin input method, I want to set the preferences for this particular input method. It should be something like "Using Traditional Characters in the IBus Pinyin IME" in [this webpage](http://www.pinyinjoe.com/linux/ubuntu-10-chinese-input-pinyin-chewing.htm).

But when I click the "Preferences" button in the floating window, as shown below, nothing appears. Clicking on Ibus icon and then "Preferences" does not work as well.

[image: button]

I tried with Pinyin and Sunpinyin, but neither gives a pop-up window. I'm expecting to a "Shuangpin" option in that window.

It's something like [this problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/427768/ibus-preferences-doesnt-show) but I'm running on a recently installed Ubuntu 14.04, xfce4, in a crouton environment.

How can I get the "Preference" window pop up?

Please note that I can type Chinese with pinyin input method. I just want to configure the preferences for that particular input method, so the problem isn't about how to install ibus or installing an input method.

Comment: I got around this problem with fcitx.

Answer (score 0):

Go to *System Settings -> Text Entry*, select Pinyin or SunPinyin and click the tool icon.

Comment: Well....thanks, but :( There isn't "Text Entry"

Comment: @Yvon: Then you don't have Ubuntu 14.04, right?

Comment: It's a crouton environment. https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton

Comment: @Yvon: Can't tell if that matters. But the desktop environment certainly does, and I see now that you have xfce, and not Unity, which I assumed when you in the title said Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Yes I use xfce, which I think does not have "Text Entry" as in Unity. But what really hurts is clicking on the button in the screenshot should yield a pop-up window, but it doesn't. Maybe Unity is the only solution, but since it's a Chromebook I don't have abundant storage for the GUI.

Comment: @Yvon: Possibly the Ubuntu specific ibus patches (due to Unity) have something to do with it. But now I'm just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue with mint mate 17.2 which seems base on ubuntu 14.04.1.

### Fix it:

And I fixed it by install python-ibus:

`sudo apt-get install python-ibus`

Then you can open the preference windows for sunpinyin.

### As a summary:

When install ibus, you better use following command:

`sudo apt-get install ibus ibus-table ibus-sunpinyin python-ibus`

Comment: Seems `python-ibus` is no longer available on some versions of Ubuntu.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is probably caused by python versions.

Don't modify ubuntu's default python version unless necessary, because that may broke various things, in my experience.

Try to run `ibus-setup`, to see what is causing the preference from starting. Then try to fix it.

---

In my case, it's because I have installed python3 *(v3.9)* via `brew`.

While the default python3 is *v3.5*, after install the system.

After uninstall brew's python via:

`brew remove python3   brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies python3`

Then re-open another terminal to take effect, then the issue is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

To copy an answer from this Launchpad thread:

```
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ibus/+bug/1730395
```

> @KANGOD install python-ibus from trusy-update will solve the problem. i download one from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/python-ibus/1.5.5-1ubuntu3.2, and install the deb with dpkg -i