# 22.04: Chinese pinyin does not work on browser

Tags: 22.04, browser, pinyin

I followed the instructions in [Ubuntu 22.04 Chinese (simplified) pinyin input support](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1408873/ubuntu-22-04-chinese-simplified-pinyin-input-support) to install Chinese pinyin input. It works on a text editor but does not work on the browser (Firefox). How can I troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

你可以试试用 IBus + Rime 的方案，之前用过 IBux 自带的 pinyin 也试过 Fcitx，似乎 Rime 这个输入法设计的更好，同时更稳定一些

**English:**

You can try to use the IBus + Rime solution, I have used the pinyin that comes with IBux before, and I have also tried Fcitx, it seems that Rime's input method is better designed, and at the same time more stable

Comment: Please translate this accepted, bountied answer into English. I can see the point of using these particular characters to make a point but even a *parallel* translation would be better suited to Ask Ubuntu...

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely an incompatibility with the sandboxed snap package of Firefox. As a workaround, [Install Firefox as an APT package](https://askubuntu.com/a/1404401/124466), so that it will behave like a native application, and will integrate better with other system services (e.g. input method).